# How would you go about solving this integral problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

How do you test the equality of these integrals when they have no numerical value?

The answer is A by the way.

Comment: HINT: Substitution is the way.

Comment: As $x$ goes from $0$ to $b-a$, $x+a$ goes from $a$ to $b$.  Thus I and II are the same.

Comment: Ah. I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Is the continuity of $f$ really necessary here?  I think it's true in general, no?

Comment: All you need is Riemann integrability.

Comment: Draw a picture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at it like this:

In the first integral arguments of $f()$ vary from $a$ to $b$. For that to be the case in *ii)*, $x+a$ must vary from $a$ to $b$ too, so $x$ varies from $a-a=0$ to $b-a$.

In *iii)* for $x+c$ to vary from $a$ to $b$, $x$ would have to vary from $a-c$ to $b-c$, which is not the case.

Comment: But for $III$, if you substitute, you would also get $b+c+c-a-c-c=b-a$ , which is the same as $I$ and $II$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: If you substitute the limits into each integral, you would get $b-a$ for all three options. This means that all three are equal, no?

Comment: No. It's not enough for the length of the interval to be the same, if that's what you mean. For us to be sure that the integral is the same, we must be integrating "the same piece" of $f$ every time. The interval in $III$ might be the same length, but it's shifted.

Comment: Oh. So the integral for $III$ would have to change to $(x-c)$. Right?

Comment: Exactly! Good job.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is (A)

To show that, let's denote the primitive of f as F on the interval we integrate on.

In case I. we have:

$$
I=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a) 
$$

In case II. we have through the substitution $u=a+x$, $du=dx$ and changing the upper and lower bounds accordingly, $b$ and $a$ respectively

$$
II=\int_{a}^{b}f(u)du=F(b)-F(a)=I 
$$

Likewise, in the last case, we have by substituting $u=x+c$, $du=dx$ and changing the bounds to $b+c+c=b+2c$ and $a+c+c=a+2c$, we have:

$$
III=\int_{a+2c}^{b+2c}f(u)du=F(b+2c)-F(a+2c)\neq I
$$

Hope it helped. Since it's my first answer on stackexchange and since my mathematics level is poor, please show me how to improve this answer.

Comment: Why are you using u-substitution? There are no numerical values assigned to the variables $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this problem without u-sub?

Comment: I don't understand your question and as I've said, my mathematics level is poor, I did what I could with the information given